# while using g.drawImage(img,0,0,100,100,0,0,0,0,null) it does not produce any result?

Tags: java, file

while using g.drawImage(img,0,0,100,100,0,0,0,0,null) it does not produce any result. So how to draw on the image in file of a better way?

Comment: The OP has posted 8 questions (not counting the multiple postings that have been deleted) and not once has the OP bothered to accept an answer. Why do you people still encourage this behaviour by providing answers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As well as ensuring the image is loaded, the last 4 int parameters are the source x,y,width,height... in specifying 0,0,0,0 you are asking the API to draw a 0x0 rectangle of the image starting at 0,0 - this should paint nothing.  You probably wanting 0,0,100,100 for these, or use the overload that does not specify two sets of coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

The last parameter in the [drawImage](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawImage(java.awt.Image,%20int,%20int,%20java.awt.Color,%20java.awt.image.ImageObserver)) method is an [ImageObserver](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/image/ImageObserver.html). Provide a valid implentation of ImageObserver, and check in the overridden `imageUpdate` method whether your image is getting updated or not.

From there on using proper debugging you can fing out why its not drawn

Answer (score 0):

Start out with just g.drawImage(img, x, y, observer); and see if you get anything. Note, the ImageObserver can be null.

Make sure that img has been loaded.

Also, make sure that the Graphics or Graphics2D object refers to something that you can see or verify the contents of. For instance, if it's a JPanel, make sure it's not hidden, etc. Or, if you're drawing to another image, try writing the image out to a file using ImageIO.write(img, "jpg", new File("test.jpg")) or something similar.